# how to run ory/hydra on docker with custom config hyda.yaml file

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

How to run ory/hydra as docker container with a custom configuration file.
Is it the best way to run or providing environment variable is better.
Need help!!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the solution mentioned above, you can also try `Docker Compose`. Personally, I prefer this as I find it easy to follow and manage.

The official 5-minute tutorial also uses `Docker Compose` which can be found here: https://www.ory.sh/hydra/docs/5min-tutorial/

I am using PostgreSQL as the database here but you can replace it with any other of the supported databases such as MySQL.

More information about supported Database configurations are here: https://www.ory.sh/hydra/docs/dependencies-environment/#database-configuration

First, you create `docker-compose.yml` like below and then just `docker-compose up`

```yaml
version: '3.7'

networks:
  intranet:
    driver: bridge

services:
  hydra-migrate:
    depends_on:
      - auth-db
    container_name: hydra-migrate
    image: oryd/hydra:v1.10.6
    environment:
      - DSN=postgres://auth:secret@auth-db:5432/auth?sslmode=disable&max_conns=20&max_idle_conns=4
    command: migrate sql -e --yes
    networks:
      - intranet

  hydra:
    container_name: hydra
    image: oryd/hydra:v1.10.6
    depends_on:
      - auth-db
      - hydra-migrate
    ports:
      - "4444:4444" # Public port
      - "4445:4445" # Admin port
      - "5555:5555" # Port for hydra token user
    command:
      serve -c /etc/hydra/config/hydra.yml all --dangerous-force-http
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - intranet
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./config
        target: /etc/hydra/config

  auth-db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: auth-db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=auth
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_DB=auth
    networks:
      - intranet
```

`hydra-migrate` service takes care of the database migrations and we don't actually need to specify an external configuration file for this and just the DSN as an environment variable would suffice.

`hydra` service starts up the hydra container and here I have done a volume mount where I have bound my local `config` folder to `/etc/hydra/config` within the container.

And then when the container spins up the following command is executed
`serve -c /etc/hydra/config/hydra.yml all --dangerous-force-http` which uses the bound config file.

And here is how my hydra config file looks like:

```yaml
## ORY Hydra Configuration
version: v1.10.6

serve:
  public:
    cors:
      enabled: true

dsn: postgres://auth:secret@auth-db:5432/auth?sslmode=disable&max_conns=20&max_idle_conns=4

oidc:
  subject_identifiers:
    supported_types:
      - public
      - pairwise
    pairwise:
      salt: youReallyNeedToChangeThis

urls:
  login: http://localhost:4455/auth/login
  consent: http://localhost:4455/auth/consent
  logout: http://localhost:4455/consent
  error: http://localhost:4455/error
  post_logout_redirect: http://localhost:3000/
  self:
    public: http://localhost:4444/
    issuer: http://localhost:4444/

ttl:
  access_token: 1h
  refresh_token: 1h
  id_token: 1h
  auth_code: 1h

oauth2:
  expose_internal_errors: true

secrets:
  cookie:
    - youReallyNeedToChangeThis
  system:
    - youReallyNeedToChangeThis

log:
  leak_sensitive_values: true
  format: json
  level: debug
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a dockerfile with this content:

```
FROM oryd/hydra:latest

COPY hydra.yml /home/ory/.hydra
COPY hydra.yml /.hydra

EXPOSE 4444 4445 5555
```

only one copy is needed but i never know which :)
you can run with env. variables as well, but I prefer the yaml, it's easier